# How to check if two urls return the same page

Tags: ruby, http, url, canonical-link

Lets assume that following urls are pointing to the same content.

- http://example.com/content?id=123
- http://example.com/content?id=123&writer=456

How can I check if those links are pointing to the same content?
I am particularly using Ruby but any other suggestion is welcome as well...

Answer (score 2):

The first naive guess is to get the content and create a hash. However, if the content has any dynamic behavior at all, this is not a good metric.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'digest/md5'

f1 = open("http://rubyonrails.org/?id=1")
c1 = f1.read
d1 = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(c1)

f2 = open("http://rubyonrails.org/");
c2 = f2.read
d2 = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(c2)

d1 == d2 # true
```

If we repeat the same thing with say: www.google.com and google.com the hashes won't match because there may be slight variations to content.

You can use the [Jaro Winkler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance) measure for strings, which gives you a value between 0 and 1 for how similar two strings are.
There's a pure [implementation](https://github.com/kiyoka/fuzzy-string-match) of the algorithm too in ruby. The native implementations are much faster. I've used the [amatch](http://flori.github.com/amatch/) library in the past.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'fuzzystringmatch'

f1 = open("http://www.google.com/")
c1 = f1.read

f2 = open("http://google.com/")
c2 = f2.read

delta = 0.1
jarow = FuzzyStringMatch::JaroWinkler.create( :pure )
distance = jarow.getDistance(c1, c2) # 0.85 .. that is the text looks to be 85% similar
```